# Program hangs in a function call to Wincrypt functions

Tags: c++, pointers

Can you help me with this code? It hangs when calling the function `AesDecrypt`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>


struct AesKey {
    BLOBHEADER Header;
    DWORD dwKeyLength;
    BYTE cbKey[16];

        AesKey() {
          ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(*this));
          Header.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
          Header.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
          Header.reserved = 0;
          Header.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_128;
          dwKeyLength = 16;
        }
};

void AesDecrypt(unsigned char *output, unsigned char *input, int inLen, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, int &plainSize) {
    HCRYPTPROV provider;
    AesKey rawKey;
    HCRYPTKEY cKey;

    BOOL hr = CryptAcquireContext(&provider, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0);
    if (hr == FALSE)
        throw "Unable to acquire AES Context";

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        rawKey.cbKey[i] = key[i];

    hr = CryptImportKey(provider, (BYTE *) &rawKey, sizeof(AesKey), NULL, 0, &cKey);
    if (hr == FALSE)
        throw "Unable to import given key";

    hr = CryptSetKeyParam(cKey, KP_IV, (BYTE *) iv, 0);
    if (hr == FALSE)
        throw "Unable to set IV";

    DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_CBC;
    hr = CryptSetKeyParam(cKey, KP_MODE, (BYTE*) &dwMode, 0);
    if (hr == FALSE)
        throw "Unable to set mode";

    memcpy(output, input, inLen);

    DWORD d = (DWORD) inLen;
    hr = CryptDecrypt(cKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, output, &d);
    if (hr == FALSE)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
        throw "Error during Decryption";
    }

    plainSize = d;
}

// codigo generado por mi

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        unsigned char input[] = "SE83loTjmMeaG9+xoIyjng==";
        unsigned char *pinput = input;

        unsigned char output[] = "SE83loTjmMeaG9+xoIyjng==";
        unsigned char *poutput = output;

        unsigned char iv[]  = "1234567890ABCDEF";
        unsigned char *piv = iv;

        unsigned char key[] = "1234567890ABCDEF";
        unsigned char *pkey = key;
        int plaInt;
        AesDecrypt(poutput, pinput, 24, pkey, piv, plaInt);

        std::cout << output << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

The code crashes when calling the function, I think I'm doing something wrong by passing pointers.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.
>
> -------------------------------- Process exited with return value 255 Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Please debug your program first before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this line is the culprit.

```
hr = CryptImportKey(provider, (BYTE *) &rawKey, sizeof(AesKey), NULL, 0, &cKey);
```

You probably meant to use

```
hr = CryptImportKey(provider, rawKey.cbKey, sizeof(AesKey), NULL, 0, &cKey);
```

Comment: produces the same error